# Java jTextField sum

Tags: java, database, netbeans, sum, jtextfield

We are working on a bookstore project. Looking at the code below, I need to add up all the DB values ​​in the price column and then output the value to the jtextfield. How should I write the code...?

Thank you for your feedback.

```
public void jTableMain() {
        MyQuery1 mq1 = new MyQuery1();
        ArrayList<Carrier1> list = mq1.BookTable1();
        String[] columnName = {"책 코드", "책 이름", "로 고", "가 격"};
        Object[][] rows = new Object[list.size()][4];
        int sum = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            rows[i][0] = list.get(i).getBook_code();
            rows[i][1] = list.get(i).getBook_name();
            
            if(list.get(i).getBookImage() != null) {
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(list.get(i).getBookImage()).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                
                rows[i][2] = image;
            }
            else{
                rows[i][2] = null;
            }
            
            rows[i][3] = list.get(i).getPrice();
           
            
        }
        
        TheModel model = new TheModel (rows, columnName);
        
        jTableMain.setModel(model); // 데이터 불러오기
        jTableMain.setRowHeight(90); // JTable 높이 지정
        jTableMain.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100); 
    
        // jTableSubMain에 데이터 불러오기
        jTableSubMain.setModel(model);
```

Comment: what are you asking us?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:  You don't have a `JTextField` in your code fragment, but you would convert the sum to a `String` and set the text of the `JTextField`.

```
public void jTableMain() {
        MyQuery1 mq1 = new MyQuery1();
        ArrayList<Carrier1> list = mq1.BookTable1();
        String[] columnName = {"책 코드", "책 이름", "로 고", "가 격"};
        Object[][] rows = new Object[list.size()][4];
        int sum = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            // Make these changes
            Carrier1 carrier = list.get(i);
            rows[i][0] = carrier.getBook_code();
            rows[i][1] = carrier.getBook_name();
            
            if(carrier.getBookImage() != null) {
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(carrier.getBookImage()).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                rows[i][2] = image;
            } else {
                rows[i][2] = null;
            }
            
            // Make these changes
            int price = carrier.getPrice();
            sum += price;
            rows[i][3] = price;
        }
        
        TheModel model = new TheModel (rows, columnName);
        
        jTableMain.setModel(model); // 데이터 불러오기
        jTableMain.setRowHeight(90); // JTable 높이 지정
        jTableMain.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100); 
    
        // jTableSubMain에 데이터 불러오기
        jTableSubMain.setModel(model);
```

Comment: When I write the code and try to put the sum into the jTextField and do getText();, an error occurs. What should I do in this case??

Comment: @In Hwan Kim: I have no idea without seeing the `JTextField` code and running it in my IDE.  That's why we always ask people to edit their questions with a [mre] completely demonstrating the problem.